# How do I allow my iOS app to send information to a server?

Tags: ios, iphone, connection, swift3

I have an unactivated iPhone so no cellular data, but it is WiFi capable. I can access Safari, slack, etc. no problem. I am making an app that is trying to send a JSON package to a server and await the servers response. But it seems that the app I am making is not even touching the Internet.

This code will return true: (google.com is just an example url)

```
func isInternetAvailable() -> Bool
{
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
        }
    }

    var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
        return false
    }
    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```

While this code will return false:

```
func checkInternet(flag:Bool, completionHandler:@escaping (_ internet:Bool) -> Void)
{
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com/")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    request.timeoutInterval = 10.0

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue:OperationQueue.main, completionHandler:
        {(response: URLResponse?, data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in

            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

            let rsp = response as! HTTPURLResponse?
            self.OutputTextField.text = self.OutputTextField.text + ", \(rsp)"

            completionHandler(rsp?.statusCode == 200)
    } as! (URLResponse?, Data?, Error?) -> Void )
}
```

I have tried many methods to send the JSON package, but most just crash the app or give no response. I put in this code to demonstrate what the app is doing in regards to the Internet connectivity. I have changed the Info.plist to allow arbitrary loads and to use WiFi. Anything to get this to work would be helpful.

Comment: Are you using a http URL or a https URL?

Comment: I am using http, but I have added the exceptions to the info.plist

Answer (score 0):

So there were several things I did wrong. The first was I was updating the UI in a background thread causing crashes. Pertaining to the server connection, right click on info.plist and edit it as an xml document and add the site exceptions that way.